# Delphi XE Update 1 - Which version number?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I cannot find in the Install and Readme file which version number is Update 1.

In Delphi, the About box says that I have Embarcadero® Delphi® XE Version 15.0.3890.34076.
Does it mean that it includes the Update 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know I have XE update 1, and my version number is 15.0.3953.35171.  So no, you don't have it.

An easier way to tell is that if you did have it, in the About box, you would see "Update 1 for Delphi XE and C++ Builder XE" listed under "Installed Updates".

Answer (score 2):

After installing Update 1, you get it listed in the "Installed Updates". Also, the version number is 15.0.3953.35171.

Comment: Damn it. I thought I already have update 1. I purchased Delphi XE after the Update 1 was launched so I supposed that the link Embarcadero gave me was the link to the latest available version. Thanks TOndrej.

Comment: Accepted - since you were the first one to answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I think Mason Wheeler was the first.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need to reinstall and want to make sure you have Update 1 already in, you can get [CC 28006](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/28006) for the Web Installer w/ Update 1, or [CC 27984](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/27984) if you prefer ISOs.  If you watch CodeCentral (and your Registered Downloads) you should see updated installers land shortly after the updaters are released.